# I can't convert an int and a float with convert.ToString() to string

Tags: c#, string

I have 2 controls in my form,one is an int and the other is a float,I tried to convert with the "Convert.toString()" method but it didn't work and I get all the time a null value
this is my code:

```
string req = "select coef from amortissement where id_amort =@p";
                    textBox4.Text =Convert.ToString(GetRecordsetValue(req, textBox1.Text) as String)

req = "select Plan from amortissement where id_amort =@p";

                    textBox3.Text =Convert.ToString(GetRecordsetValue(req, textBox1.Text) as String);
```

this is the GetRecordsetValue method:

```
private Object GetRecordsetValue(string req, string sValParam)
        {
            // ExecuteScalar est optimisée pour récupérer une seule valeur
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand(req, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", sValParam);
                return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch
            {

                return String.Empty;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

thanks for Help

Comment: What are the data types of the `coef` and `Plan` fields? Your code would only work if it a text/varchar type fields, i.e. returned as a strings from the database.

Comment: Please show the code of GetRecordsetValue....

Comment: thanks Guffa it's a nvarchar(50)

Comment: Now it is clear that if your query doesn't find any recod matching the WHERE condition the return from GetRecordsetValue is a null and passing a NULL to Convert.ToString() throws the exception

Comment: @steve thanks for your reply but I have records concerning this 2 informations in my database Table with this id_amort :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `GetRecordsetValue` returns NULL if your query doesn't find any record matching the WHERE condition. The null value returned is passed back to Convert.ToString() and this throws the exception

```
  string req = "select coef from amortissement where id_amort =@p";
  object result = GetRecordsetValue(req, textBox1.Text);
  if(result != null)
  {
      textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
  }
  else
  {
      // and/or a message to the user to correct its inputs.
      textBox4.Text = "";
  }
```

There is also the problem of the value passed inside the `GetRecordsetValue`. This value is passed as a string and it is added inside the parameter collection as a string datatype. If the field `id_amort` is not a string (as it seems from its name) then it is highly probable that your query cannot find the record.

I suggest to create different overloads of GetRecordsetValue. One that takes an integer for example

Comment: thanks steve it helps me a lot,I have an other question pleaze how can I convert a float to string with comma and dot

Comment: Perhaps you could use `floatValue.ToString("#,###.##")`, but it is better if you prepare a new question with your requirements clearly described. This will attract the attention of a lot more of users.